# How to retrieve step count in a Job?

Tags: java, android

Here, [Motion sensors - Use the step counter sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion), it is said that *To preserve the battery on devices running your app, you should use the JobScheduler class to retrieve the current value from the step counter sensor at a specific interval.*

And that's what I have done. My class extending the `Job` class registers the `TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` but it barely receives the `onSensorChanged` event. When I launch my app, the job is started as well and it receives an event, which is useless because my app receives it as well. When the app is closed, the `Job` is regularly started and stopped by the system, but it almost never receives an event in which I could get the step count.

Does anyone know how to use the `JobSheduler` and the `Job`s it schedules to get the step count?